Dynamic meta titles for pages with dynamic name in URL?
I've got some pages with urls like this: /state/state-name/ and /city/city-name/  that's built in WordPress.
The states and city's are dynamically added when they have been populated by a user entering that information.
The URL parameter of "state-name" & "city-name" determines the content that will dynamically show on that page. However, my meta title & description for all those pages is statically set. Is there a way I can dynamically set the meta title & description based on the page content?
I've tried the following, but can only get it to work for one page (/state/).
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'custom_title');

function custom_title( $title ) {
    $uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/state/' === $uri ) {       
        return $title . ' - Some text';
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter('wpseo_description', 'custom_meta');

function custom_meta($description) {
    $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if ('/state/' === $uri) {
        return $description . ' state meta.';
    }
    return $description;
}

Works only for url /state/.
How to get it to work with other dynamic url's like those below?
/state/something1/
/state/something2/
/state/etc/

/city1/something1/
/city1/something2/
/city1/etc/

Could it be done with something like a wildcard, i.e.,
/state/ * / and /city/ * /
Any pointers appreciated.
